# neo4j user defined procedure: "cannot find symbol: class Transaction"

Tags: maven, neo4j-java-api

I am trying to build a simple user defined procedure using [the example user defined procedure supplied by neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template).  However, when I try to get a Transaction instance using "Transaction tx = db.beginTx()", the compiler complains that it cannot resolve the symbol for Transaction.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was very simple.  Simply import the Transaction package "org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction"